# Why the value of x2 is reducing?

Tags: slope

The slope is given by $ \frac{y1-y2}{x1-x2}$

If the slope is given we can also calculate the value of x2.

slope= $ \frac{y1-y2}{x1-x2}$

x1-x2= $\frac{y1-y2}{slope}$

x2=x1-$ \frac{y1-y2}{slope}$

Suppose a triangle we have [traingle image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PFHR.png) so when we move from y1 to y2 the value of x coordinate is changed to x2 which is greater than x1 but when i used the above formula to find value of x2 its giving me a value which is less than x1.

Why its so?

Comment: "when i used the above formula to find value of x2 its giving me a value which is less than x1" -- I don't believe it. Show your work so someone can tell you your mistake.

Comment: Let slope =1.73                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       Let x1=100 y1=100                                                                                                                    y2=99  x2 = (x1-(y1-y2)/slope) = 100-(1/1.73) = 99.4219                                                    x2 is less than x1 it must be greater according to fig [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PFHR.png)

Comment: @David I found my mistake.